# Homography algorithm not working as expected

Tags: algorithm, matrix, openframeworks, homography

Recently I've been trying to complete a stage of my project by generating a homography 3x3 matrix from 4 detected and 4 truth 2D points.
I've tried a few different algorithms and a few different SVD implementations and still can't get a good result.

I've taken [Openframework's homography implementation](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/quad-warping-homography-without-opencv/3121/21) (which IIRC is taken from opencv) and getting close... but still not correct results. I'm pretty sure all the matrix usages are correct but made I've messed up somewhere (maybe even the final transform??)

Here is an image of the points I'm trying to match, src(matches) on left, dst (truth) on the right. (I can get coords if desired but image size is around 640x1000). The far right (coloured on white) is the matches transformed onto the dst/truth, and an imaged warped by the same homography used in the test code.
[image]

note: ignore the opencl types, these are all used correctly(just cut down for brevity here). std::Debug is just an ostream. It's a 16 float array, but I'm just using the first 9

```html
void gaussian_elimination(float *input, int n)
{
 // ported to c from pseudocode in
 // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination
 
 float * A = input;
 int i = 0;
 int j = 0;
 int m = n-1;
 while (i < m && j < n){
  // Find pivot in column j, starting in row i:
  int maxi = i;
  for(int k = i+1; k<m; k++){
   if(fabs(A[k*n+j]) > fabs(A[maxi*n+j])){
    maxi = k;
   }
  }
  if (A[maxi*n+j] != 0){
   //swap rows i and maxi, but do not change the value of i
   if(i!=maxi)
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
     float aux = A[i*n+k];
     A[i*n+k]=A[maxi*n+k];
     A[maxi*n+k]=aux;
    }
   //Now A[i,j] will contain the old value of A[maxi,j].
   //divide each entry in row i by A[i,j]
   float A_ij=A[i*n+j];
   for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
    A[i*n+k]/=A_ij;
   }
   //Now A[i,j] will have the value 1.
   for(int u = i+1; u< m; u++){
    //subtract A[u,j] * row i from row u
    float A_uj = A[u*n+j];
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
     A[u*n+k]-=A_uj*A[i*n+k];
    }
    //Now A[u,j] will be 0, since A[u,j] - A[i,j] * A[u,j] = A[u,j] - 1 * A[u,j] = 0.
   }
   
   i++;
  }
  j++;
 }
 
 //back substitution
 for(int i=m-2;i>=0;i--){
  for(int j=i+1;j<n-1;j++){
   A[i*n+m]-=A[i*n+j]*A[j*n+m];
   //A[i*n+j]=0;
  }
 }
}
                                  
                                  
                                  
cl_float16 of_findHomography(cl_float2 src[4], cl_float2 dst[4])
{
 // create the equation system to be solved
 //
 // from: Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision 2ed
 //       Hartley R. and Zisserman A.
 //
 // x' = xH
 // where H is the homography: a 3 by 3 matrix
 // that transformed to inhomogeneous coordinates for each point
 // gives the following equations for each point:
 //
 // x' * (h31*x + h32*y + h33) = h11*x + h12*y + h13
 // y' * (h31*x + h32*y + h33) = h21*x + h22*y + h23
 //
 // as the homography is scale independent we can let h33 be 1 (indeed any of the terms)
 // so for 4 points we have 8 equations for 8 terms to solve: h11 - h32
 // after ordering the terms it gives the following matrix
 // that can be solved with gaussian elimination:
 
 float P[8][9]={
  {-src[0][0], -src[0][1], -1,   0,   0,  0, src[0][0]*dst[0][0], src[0][1]*dst[0][0], -dst[0][0] }, // h11
  {  0,   0,  0, -src[0][0], -src[0][1], -1, src[0][0]*dst[0][1], src[0][1]*dst[0][1], -dst[0][1] }, // h12
  
  {-src[1][0], -src[1][1], -1,   0,   0,  0, src[1][0]*dst[1][0], src[1][1]*dst[1][0], -dst[1][0] }, // h13
  {  0,   0,  0, -src[1][0], -src[1][1], -1, src[1][0]*dst[1][1], src[1][1]*dst[1][1], -dst[1][1] }, // h21
  
  {-src[2][0], -src[2][1], -1,   0,   0,  0, src[2][0]*dst[2][0], src[2][1]*dst[2][0], -dst[2][0] }, // h22
  {  0,   0,  0, -src[2][0], -src[2][1], -1, src[2][0]*dst[2][1], src[2][1]*dst[2][1], -dst[2][1] }, // h23
  
  {-src[3][0], -src[3][1], -1,   0,   0,  0, src[3][0]*dst[3][0], src[3][1]*dst[3][0], -dst[3][0] }, // h31
  {  0,   0,  0, -src[3][0], -src[3][1], -1, src[3][0]*dst[3][1], src[3][1]*dst[3][1], -dst[3][1] }, // h32
 };
 
 gaussian_elimination(&P[0][0],9);
/*
 // gaussian elimination gives the results of the equation system
 // in the last column of the original matrix.
 // opengl needs the transposed 4x4 matrix:
 float aux_H[]=
 {
  P[0][8],P[3][8],0,P[6][8], // h11  h21 0 h31
  P[1][8],P[4][8],0,P[7][8], // h12  h22 0 h32
  0      ,      0,0,0,       // 0    0   0 0
  P[2][8],P[5][8],0,1 // h13  h23 0 h33
 };
*/
 // non transposed 3x3
 cl_float16 Result;
 Result.s[0] = P[0][8];
 Result.s[1] = P[1][8];
 Result.s[2] = P[2][8];
 
 Result.s[3] = P[3][8];
 Result.s[4] = P[4][8];
 Result.s[5] = P[5][8];
 
 Result.s[6] = P[6][8];
 Result.s[7] = P[7][8];
 Result.s[8] = 1;
 //Result.s[8] = P[8][8];

 
 // test
 for ( int i=0; i<4; i++ )
 {
  auto H = Result.s;
  float x = H[0]*src[i][0] + H[1]*src[i][1] + H[2];
  float y = H[3]*src[i][0] + H[4]*src[i][1] + H[5];
  float z = H[6]*src[i][0] + H[7]*src[i][1] + H[8];
  
  x /= z;
  y /= z;
  
  float diffx = dst[i][0] - x;
  float diffy = dst[i][1] - y;
  std::Debug << "err src->dst #" << i << ": " << diffx << "," << diffy << std::endl;
 }
 for ( int i=0; i<4; i++ )
 {
  auto H = Result.s;
  float x = H[0]*dst[i][0] + H[1]*dst[i][1] + H[2];
  float y = H[3]*dst[i][0] + H[4]*dst[i][1] + H[5];
  float z = H[6]*dst[i][0] + H[7]*dst[i][1] + H[8];
  
  x /= z;
  y /= z;
  
  float diffx = src[i][0] - x;
  float diffy = src[i][1] - y;
  std::Debug << "err src->dst #" << i << ": " << diffx << "," << diffy << std::endl;
 }

 
 return Result;
}
```

The output from the image is

> err src->dst #0: 0.00195,0.0132
>
> err src->dst #1: 0,6.1e-05
>
> err src->dst #2: -0.00161,-8.96e-05
>
> err src->dst #3: 1.91e-06,0.000122
>
> err dst->src #0: 2.31e+03,551
>
> err dst->src #1: -3.34e+03,-4.23e+03
>
> err dst->src #2: 1.07e+03,1.25e+04
>
> err dst->src #3: 456,771

Is there anything obviously wrong with my matrix transform code? 
or am I putting the SVD results into the matrix in the wrong row/col order?
Maybe the whole algorithm isn't what I need? (surely it should generate quite a simple, small, rotation matrix?)

Comment: What about using cv::findHomography ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using opencv entirely for one single algorithm, this will be cross platform, I also need speed, so want to avoid converting to/from cv::mat, AND this is going into opencl & gles compute kernels (this code already runs in kernels... just incorrectly :)

Comment: My next test step will be to run everything through opencv and debug the differences/results though

Answer (score 0):

My bad as usual. This implementation seems to work perfectly (so far) and will be great for GPU parallelisation.

I was feeding in bad coordinates. The points rendered were different to the points input into the algorithm (new code vs old code).

A warning for the future to always generate the data first, THEN render, not render&generate with [what was once] the same code.